# Getting ASP dropdownlist selected value using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in asp as below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActiveStatus" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" onchange = "dconfirm()" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "ddlActiveStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Y</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="N">N</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I would like to retrieve the value of selected index when user selects on a different set of values. I have a code like this:

```
function dconfirm(){
var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlActiveStatus.ClientID%>");
var selVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selVal);}
```

Expected result is when user selects 'Y', the javascript will alert 'Y'. However the program kept throwing below error:

> The name 'ddlActiveStatus' does not exist in the current context

I would like to get it done using javascript only. What have I missed out? Kindly advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Yup it's in aspx page.

Comment: Can you access it in code behind??

Comment: I've copy pasted your code and it's work. maybe the problem is in something besides these codes. Is `ddlActiveStatus` is in repeater or something? If it is so, you can't access it in plain javascript like that.

Comment: Check the correct id for ddlActiveStatus  after page load. if its not concatenated with unique id

Answer (score 0):

While technically what you're doing should work, you can avoid referencing ddlActiveStatus.ClientID in your JavaScript by adding ClientIDMode="Static" directly on the ddlActiveStatus control.

Doing this gives you full control over the ID generated for the control so you can then simply use the following in your JavaScript:

```html
var e = document.getElementById("ddlActiveStatus");
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP sometimes changes the ID. Add a "Name" to the element like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList Name="DdlActiveStatus" ID="ddlActiveStatus" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" onchange = "dconfirm()" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddlActiveStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Then use: var x = document.getElementsByName("DdlActiveStatus");

Or, you could use jquery:
$('[name="DdlActiveStatus"]').doStuff();

Comment: Your code led me some direction, however I still have some trouble. When I'm trying to alert(x), it gave me '[object]'. I then use var selVal = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value to retrieve its selected value, however it gave me nothing at all. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ddlActiveStatusoption').val()
```

or

```
$('select#ddlActiveStatusoption:selected').val())
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround for this. Hopefully it'll be able to help someone who're looking for answer.

Instead of getting the selected values of ddlActiveStatus in my javascript, I'll be passing the value by adding below code to my dropdownlist property as below:

```
onchange = "dconfirm(this.value)"
```

As for my javascript function it'll display the user selected value. Code as below:

```
function dconfirm(values)
{
    alert(values);

    if (values == 'Y')
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This does the job for me. Hope it helps.

Thanks guys for your helpful replies, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way for me is

```
var VarName = $('#<%=YouDropDownId.ClientId %>').val();
```

for your case you forget # 
try this i hope it works

```
var e = document.getElementById('#<%=ddlActiveStatus.ClientID %>');
```

good luck.